# How to read Image and corresponding Text file from folder and Save Image in other folder base on Label

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection

I have a dataset in which one folder contains Images and other folder contain corresponding text files. Each text file contain a label of corresponding Class.

```
Images folder 
          image_0000.jpeg 
          image_0001.jpeg

Label folder 
          image_0000.txt
          image_0001.txt
```

The label text file contain value of 0 or 1 or 2.

I want to save Images which correspond to Label 0 in another Folder .similarly for remaining Labels 1,2

As you can see in the following Image.

[Dataset Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snfe5.jpg)

```
def read_image_list(image_list_file):
    f = open(image_list_file, 'r')
    filenames = []
  
    for line in f:
        filename, label = line[:-1].split(' ')
        filenames.append(filename)
        
    return filenames
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the first three directory variables will make the code work like a charm. The answer given by Prem J is also cool.

```
import os
import shutil

# assumung that the names of the images and the labels are same excepth the extension

image_dir = "f1/im"  # Images directory path
label_dir = "f1/la"  # Labels directory path

final_dir = "f1/dataset" # the dataset directory where you want to save the images as label folders

images = os.listdir(image_dir)  # list of all the images names
label = os.listdir(label_dir)  # list of all the label names

# Sorting it to make sure the images and the labels are on the same index

images = sorted(images)   # ['test 1.jpg', 'test 2.jpg', 'test 3.jpg', 'test 4.jpg', 'test 5.jpg'] 
label = sorted(label) # ['test 1.txt', 'test 2.txt', 'test 3.txt', 'test 4.txt', 'test 5.txt']

if not os.path.exists(final_dir):
    os.mkdir(final_dir)

for c, txt in enumerate(label):
    txt_path = os.path.join(label_dir, txt)
    img_path = os.path.join(image_dir, images[c])
    with open(txt_path, "r") as r:
        l = r.read()

    dst = f"{final_dir}/{l}"
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.mkdir(dst)
    
    shutil.copy(img_path, dst)
    shutil.copy(txt_path, dst)
```